# Save line breaks from String in JavaScript object to transfer over to breaks in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

sorry if this a pretty basic question but I'm trying to store a multi-paragraph chunk of text in an object in a Pinia store to be converted to text in HTML, but I can't figure out how to transfer paragraph breaks through the Pinia store.

```js
export const useContentStore = defineStore('contentStore', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      guides: [{
        description: 'Paragraph one. Paragraph two. Paragraph three.',
      }],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<template>
  <main class="content-page">
    <body>
      <p>{{ content.description }}</p>
    </body>
  </main>
</template>
```

I'd like there to be some space between each paragraph, I don't know if that would be adding another line between them or something different. I've already tried escaping like `\n`, adding `<br>` tags in the text, and using template literals.

This is what my end goal is:

```
Paragraph one.

Paragraph two.

Paragraph three.
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: How do you know where to break text, if the paragraphs are only separated by a period and space, just as regular sentences are?

Comment: You can use a [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) element which will preserve white-space including newlines ('\n').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

```html
<p>
Paragraph one.

Paragraph two.

Paragraph three.
</p>
```

As you can see above, if you use css property **white-space: pre-wrap**, it can do what you ask, but be carefull, it may cause other weird interactions.
It will preserve whitespaces, newlines, tabs and `<br />`.

Comment: This worked great, thank you. Now I'm trying to add code blocks/markdown to the original string to transfer through to the `<p>` tag, do you know how I would be able to do that?

Comment: Not quite sure what you trying to do, but if you want to show code or something like that, while keeping formatting, you can try <pre> tag instead of <p>

Comment: I got it working another way, thanks for your help!